# Why does my C program crash?

Tags: c, crash, calculator

When I run this program from the msys command line, it tells opens a window called calc.exe (name of program) with the following error:
calc.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.

here is my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int num1, num2, ans;

    hist_file_create();

    if (argc < 2 || argc > 2)
        kill("ERROR: Use: calc <operation_type>");

    char operation_type = argv[2][0];

    switch(operation_type)
    {
        // Addition
        case 'a':
            printf("Enter a number:\n");
            scanf("%d", &num1);
            printf("Enter a second number\n");
            scanf("%d", &num2);
            ans = num1 + num2;
            printf("%d + %d = %d", num1, num2, ans);
            break;

        // Operation type list
        case 'l':
           operation_type_list();
           break;

        default:
            kill("Invalid operation type. To see a list of recognised operation types, type l");
    }
    system("PAUSE");

}
```

I know it is still probably very messy, but right nnow I am just trying to make it work, and clean it up later.
Any additional information you may need I will give.

Comment: can you put complete code, i mean the definitions of `hist_file_create()` and `operation_type_list()`?

Comment: yeah. i can pastebin it if youd like

Comment: @mat - ita crashes when i run the program from the command line, with "calc a" or "calc l". instead of executing the code for either of those two cases, it crashes

Comment: @Sagar Rakshe - http://pastebin.com/P7VtwKks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition makes sure that you have exactly 2 arguments or the program exists
    if (argc < 2 || argc > 2)
        kill("ERROR: Use: calc ");

However the next line is accessing the third argument 
   char operation_type = argv[2][0];

Which does not exist. And the program is killed

Comment: i changed the if statement to: if (argc < 3 || argc > 3) and now it does not crash. thx for that. but instead of executing whichever case i tell it to, it executes the kill("ERROR: Use: calc <operation_tyype>");

Comment: If you changed the argc condition it means you want 3 arguments, or call kill. Obviously if you call it without the 3 arguments it will exit (remember the first argument is always the executable name).


I strongly suspect that the change you wanted to make was 
char operation_type = argv[1][0]

So the program still accepts 2 arguments (1st argument calc, 2nd argument <operation_type>)

You then figure out the operation type from the second argument first character: argv[1][0]

Always remember that the compiler will do exactly what you tell it to do nothing less nothing more.

Comment: yessssssss. i see it now. thank you odedsh. i shall attempt to fix this!

Comment: IT WORKS. thank you to all who spent time halping me.